# iOs: (Swift 3) I initialized with var variable: [[Any]] = [], but an error message [type 'Any' has no subscript members]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I initialized a variable with var timeTableTemp: [[Any]] = [], but impossible to exploit the result when I fill it with:

```
timeTableTemp[i][j] = [Date1, Date2]
```

When I try to exploit the result with:

```
let slot = self.timeTableTemp[i][j]
print(slot[1])
```

I have that error message: **"type 'Any' has no subscript members"**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change you array declaration to  `[[[Date]]]`. Btw this looks extremely complex. You should post what you are trying to accomplish. There is probably an easier way to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slot` contains your dates (`[Date1, Date2]`), but the compiler doesn't know that: Your array is of type `[[Any]]`, which means `slot` is presented as `Any`.

You could cast it to an array in order to use the subscript functionality, e.g.:

```
(slot as! [Date])[0]
```

A much better solution would be to change your data model to `[[[Date]]]`, so the compiler can infer `slot`'s type:

```
var timeTableTemp: [[[Date]]] //...
let slot = timeTableTemp[i][j]
print(slot[1]) // slot is of type [Date] now and supports subscripting
```

You should try to avoid `Any` wherever possible: Swift has an awesome type system that you're throwing away when using `Any`.

Comment: Don't suggest to force cast. Use if let and cast it safely.Much better to change the array type. btw He would also need to check the array count before trying to subscript the array.

Comment: Updated my answer using your feedback

Comment: still missing the check to array count. it would crash the app if you pass an invalid index

Comment: @Leo Dabus: The problem with the [[[Date]]] = [] is that it makes another error message that I couldn't resolve too. The problem was on the line                     for model in models {
                        let modelArray = Array(repeating: 0, count:model.slots.count)
                        self.timeTableTemp.append(modelArray)
                    }    It was saying :Cannot convert value of type [Int] to expected argument type [[Date]]

Comment: try passing `[]` instead of `0`. But I still think you should use a different approach. without a complete http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it would be impossible to help you

Comment: @Leo Dabus: Okay I understand why it doesn't work with the [[[Date]]]. It is because of the initialization self.timeTableTemp.append(Array(repeating: 0, count:model.slots.count)). I should initialize with a Date and not an Int. My mistake... Thanks to all of you guys :D